# C: Writing a proper time-out

Tags: c, timer, timeout, signals, handler

Upon closely scouring through resources, I'm still not entirely sure how to write a proper and usable timer function in C.  I am not working with threads (or parallelizable code).  I simply want to write a stopwatch function that I can use to trigger a bit of code after a small amount of time has passed.

This is a very common use of a timer, in the situation of "time-out", where I have a client-server set up where the client is sending some data (UDP style with sendto(...) and recvfrom(...)).  I have written my system so that the client sends a chunk of data in a packet struct I have defined, and the server processes it via CRC then sends back an acknowledgement packet (ACK) that the msg was received uncorrupted.  However, I want to implement a time-out, where if the client does not receive an ACK in a certain period of time, the client resends the data chunk (of course the server is rigged to check for duplicates).  I want to nest this bit of timer code in the client, and for some reason do not think this should be so difficult.

I have dug up old signal handling code from work I had done long ago, as this seems to be the only way I commonly see mentioned as a solution, can someone please guide me as to how I can use the following signal handling code to not just receive a timed signal but trigger an action of some sort.  Conceptually, I feel it would be:  "send data, start timer, after timer expires  execute a resend, reset timer...repeat until that ACK received".  Better yet, would be an easier way of writing a timer function, but it doesn't look like there's much hope for that given C is a low-level language....

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

extern char *strsignal(int sig);

void timer_handler(int a)
{
  // handle signal
  printf(">>>> signal caught\n");
  printf(">>>>    int parameter = %s\n", (char*) strsignal(a));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int retval;
  struct itimerval timerValue;
  struct itimerval oldTimerValue;
  struct sigaction action;

  action.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
  action.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;

  // initialize timer parameters: expires in 5 seconds
  timerValue.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
  timerValue.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

  timerValue.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
  timerValue.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

  // install signal handler to catch SIGALRM
  //signal(SIGALRM, timer_handler);
  sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL);

  retval = setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timerValue, &oldTimerValue);

  if (-1 == retval)
    perror("Could not set timer");

  while(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should look at the [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) function, which lets you wait for data to be received at a socket, as well as specifying a timeout value. Does that sound like what you want?

Comment: Thanks @Xymostech.  Much appreciated, and I have credited you in my "what did I finally do" answer since you were the one to point out the use of "select".

Answer (score 0):

Xymostech provided the exact function I needed and after consulting the API for "select", which includes a small usage example, I modified the code there to fit what I needed and wrote a socket timer (for reads, those it's pretty simple to extend towards writes and such, as "select" has parameters for enabling this kind of check).  Make sure you've included the following libraries as specified by the "select" API:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

The following is the waittoread(...) function I created from the API example and works pretty well.  This works well in the domain of my specific problem, however, if one is looking for a more generalized timer (i.e. not just for timing socket read and writes, or file descriptors) please consult signal handling (somewhat in the spirit of the code I posted in my initial question).

```
#define S1READY 0x01 // necessary for the function's bitwise OR operation
int waittoread(int s1, int timeout_value){
   fd_set fds; // create set of sockets to be waited on
   struct timeval timeout; // the time-out value
   int rc; // # of sockets that are ready before timer expires
   int result;

   /* Set time limit. */
   timeout.tv_sec = timeout_value;
   timeout.tv_usec = 0;
   /* Create a descriptor set containing the socket.  */
   FD_ZERO(&fds); // MACRO to reset the socket storage set so new ones can be added
   FD_SET(s1, &fds); // add the socket descriptor into the socket set to wait on
   rc = select(sizeof(fds)*4, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout); // build the socket-wait system
   // another way of calling select that would be a better approach:
   // rc = select(s1 + 1), &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
   if (rc==-1) {
      perror("Error:  Call to select failed.");
      return -1;
   }
   result = 0;
   if (rc > 0){
      if (FD_ISSET(s1, &fds)) result |= S1READY;  // if the result is non-zero, perform a BIT-wise OR to extract the true socket count #
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `select` should be one plus the largest file descriptor that you want to wait for. So in this case, you should be using `s1+1`.

Comment: You're right, interestingly enough both will work, as the code above worked just fine (yielded same results).  However, it does make sense to do it in the manner you propose (I was just following the spirit of the example that was on the online source).  I will update the above with your approach in a comment as I tested and it works as well.